# Rocket.chat Accounts signin/signups integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rocket.chat

I’m currently developing a spring boot app (J2EE) and I have a Rocket.chat instance that should be integrated with it just in the authentication part.
So I got my spring boot app where users can create their accounts and it should also gets created on the rocket.chat automatically also when an existent user login to my spring boot app he also get logged in to rocket.chat automatically. so when he go to my Rocket.chat link he’ll find himself already logged in.
I searched the rockets.chat docs, I saw many authentication options but I don’t know which one will work for me, and how I’ll get it to work.

It would be great if someone could help me or link me to a tutorial to help me set this up.

PS: the Spring boot app use a MySQL database to store users information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends on what you are familiar with.
Personally I’d recommend oauth or something for simplicity. But you’d probably have to write something your self.

Once you have that coded check out our documentation for how to setup oauth with Rocket.Chat